# Help finding SO podcast on human or bot

Tags: discussion, captcha, podcast

Can someone please help me find SO podcast, where [Jeff Attwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) was annoyed with a person posting spam questions, by entering captcha values.

It was an incident where questions with same title and text were posted numerous times within minutes. And it continued for a while until Jeff and SO team put some mechanism to stop the user from doing so.

Jeff mentioned that the user passed human or bot test.

The user him self commented on the podcast and said he was doing it for good reasons rather than evil.

I am 99% sure it was in one of the SO podcasts.

But I am not able to find it. Can anyone help me find it, if the context is good enough to recognize the podcast?

Comment: You could use google, perhaps the blog summaries talk about it; use `site:blog.stackoverflow.com "by Jeff Atwood" podcast` to search through all SO podcast posts, or use `site:stackoverflow.fogbugz.com` to search through all the transcripts (not always complete)

Comment: And why specifically a moderator? Anyone can listen to the podcasts, and moderators are not required to have listened to them all or have more specific search options.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, probably because I voted for the moderator (you) :D! Just kidding, Undo rightly edited the question. Besides I was under impression that moderators would have access to some kind of summaries of these podcasts. Anyways, you are doing a good job, keep it up! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Search for `site:blog.stackoverflow.com captcha spam`.

First result returned is [New Question / Answer Rate Limits](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/):

> That is, until tonight, when we were hit by a malicious user of a type we haven't seen before

...

> But in all seriousness, the surprising thing here is that this user was not a bot. Our anti-bot stuff would be challenging to get around. It was an actual human being, entering the CAPTCHAs, cutting and pasting text into every post. We verified this by looking at the logs, and the timestamps on the entries. The times are slow and variable, not at all what you'd expect to see from a bot.

And the comment from the user:

> Hey guys, It was only a bit of fun, I didn't mean any harm to the actual site or the users. I knew it would be handled pretty soon anyways so I figured I'd exploit it while it was available ;) One correction, I wasn't copying and pasting the text, if you click back twice the text is kept intact by the browser and then you just type in the captcha and its posted (LOL) Don't hate me or all aussies for it (and especially not 2pac)! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/) mentioned in [DavidPostill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3536342/davidpostill)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311792/5645405) was discussed in [Stack Overflow Podcast #43](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/podcast-43/) (starts 44 minutes in):

> We have a lot of anti-bot code on Stack Overflow. What we didn't think
> about was [human-entered
> spam](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/)!
> Now we do -- yet another example of the incredible power of [rate
> limiting
> techniques](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001228.html).